# Can't use Wifi after BitLocker activation

Tags: linux, windows-10, wireless-networking, bitlocker

I have a dual boot Win10/Debian11 system where the wifi adapter (Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter) was working fine on both.

After installing some Win10 updates and rebooting, and then activating BitLocker for the first time on that PC, it was still working fine, but after the next reboot, it does not work in any of the two OSs, although on Windows I can see the Wifi AP list, while on Linux the device is totally off:

On Windows it always says "It was not possible to connect to this network", after trying with 2 different APs where all the rest of the devices work fine

On Linux I can't even see the device. These are the messages in dmesg that contain "error" or "fail"

```
[    0.830381] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
[    0.830667] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
[    1.000028] pci 10000:e0:1c.4: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[    1.000036] pci 10000:e0:17.0: BAR 4: failed to assign [io  size 0x0020]
[    1.000037] pci 10000:e0:17.0: BAR 2: failed to assign [io  size 0x0008]
[    1.000038] pci 10000:e0:17.0: BAR 3: failed to assign [io  size 0x0004]
[    1.000254] pcieport 10000:e0:1c.4: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
[    9.171015] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    9.667548] rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to download firmware
[    9.667804] rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
[    9.667806] rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip information
[    9.668684] rtw_8822ce: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -22
[   10.450582] hp_wmi: query 0x4c returned error 0x6
```

On BIOS Setup I haven't touched any settings (TPM on and Secure Boot off) - it has been like that since I installed Linux

Is there any possible relation between BitLocker and devices or drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitLocker doesn't interact with other hardware in that way.

You mentioned you installed Windows Updates prior to activating BitLocker.
Did that by any chance include a driver/firmware update for the Realtek Wifi chip?
(Hard to tell. I know. Microsoft seems to think nobody needs to know what they put in an update.)
This looks more as if a partial/botched driver/firmware update left the Wifi chip in a somewhat unusable state.

As it is a PCIe adapter it is removable. I would pull the card from the PC.
Boot in Windows to let Windows know it is gone. Boot into Linux for the same reason.
Then re-install the card (if possible in another PCIe slot as well) and boot into Linux FIRST.
Then try Windows.
With little luck the card will be re-detected and the drivers loaded properly.

Please note: If Windows updated firmware on the card it may refuse to work under Linux at all until Linux gets updated drivers as well. That could take a while.

Comment: There is actually a suspicious entry in `Update history > Driver Updates`: `HP Inc. - SoftwareComponent - 1.31.2309.0` installed on 26/04/2021, but no way of telling what it is

Comment: @golimar It happens sometimes that Windows 10 mis-identifies a device as a certain brand/model and throws drivers on it that don't exactly match. You could try to get the latest drivers directly from RealTek and see if they work better. (Unfortunately if such a mis-identification is your problem Windows 10 will keep trying to put their idea of the correct driver back with annoying regularity.)

Comment: It was probably a botched HP firmware update that got auto-installed. A BIOS update fixed it in both OS

Comment: @golimar I've seen a couple of cases (on HP laptops) where the Wifi (or Bluetooth) driver got an update and the Bios at the same time. If only one of them was installed the Wifi (or Bluetooth) wouldn't work until the other was updated too. Seems you have run into the same thing.